# Share session between rails 3 and rails 4 apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session, cookies

I've found some links here on stackoverflow and much more outside but they did not help me. Currently I have two applications: R3 (on rails 3) and R4 (on rails 4). Both use cookie store to store session.

Cookie store:

```
# R4
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app.com_session', :domain => ".app.com", tld_length: 2
```

I pasted the same keys for:

```
# R4:
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.secret_key = 'SECRET'
end

# R3:
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.secret_key = 'SECRET'
end
```

---

```
# R4:
production:
  secret_key_base: 'TOKEN'

# R3:
MyApp::Application.config.secret_token = 'TOKEN'
```

Also I changed the cookie serialization for R4 app:

```
# R4
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_serializer = :marshal
```

But it does not work.

It seems like Rails 4 approach to cookie store was changed and they are not compatible. Is there any way to share session between two applications R3 and R4?

UPDATE:

Currently I have a bunch of R3 applications sharing session already. That's why it is difficult for me to upgrade all the R3 apps. The main question: what is the easiest way to make R3 and R4 both talk the same language.

Is there any way to downgrade R4 cookies processing algorithm? I also think about storing all sessions in the database (it does not seem to be changed in R4).

Comment: rails 4 encrypts the cookies, rails 3 only base64 encodes them - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877820/difference-between-sessionfood-and-cookies-permanentfood/19878166#19878166 for more info - you might be able to 'upgrade' your rails 3 app to use the rails 4 cookie encryption?

Comment: Unfortunately it is really difficult to upgrade all the R3 apps to R4. I've updated the question. Take a look please.

Comment: take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616511/sharing-cookies-between-rails-3-and-rails-4-1

Comment: Thank you! But I've already read the post. They also say that simple method (unset secret_key_base and set secret_token) does not work. I think that switching to ActiveRecord store will be the easiest solution. Will try that soon. Anyway thank you for the help!